# Why do I get this error in my JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic, html-table

I have a html file with Javascript scripts inside. When I right click on the file, open with Firefox locally, it works perfectly fine. However, when I put the file on the server, the Javascript doesn't work as I expect and I have this error -

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'rows' of null

```
var tableResult = document.getElementById("tableForChange");
    for (var y=1; y < tableResult.rows.length;){ //error on this line
```

tableResult is a html table. Everything works fine when I open the file locally.

tableResult is a html table generated by applying an XSL transformation to an XML document. as part of the XSL transformation I do `<table id="tableForChange">`. When I open the file locally and inspect element, the table has the id. However, when I load the file online and I inspect element, the table doesn't have an id.

Comment: `tableResult` is empty. It didn't return an element. Probably the element isn't on the page at the time this script is invoked or you made a typo in the selector.

Comment: But it works when i open the file locally?

Comment: :-( you aren't supporting MSIE11

Comment: No errors on Firefox.

Comment: When you try to use contains or equals in the drop-down-menu, it doesn't do what it does when i open it locally

Comment: the id "tableForChange" was given to the table using an XSL transformation. Could that be the source of error?

Answer (score 1):

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'rows' of null
```

So the object that you are accessing the property `rows` on is actually `null`.

Which means that `tableResult` is `null`.

Which means that `document.getElementById("tableForChange")` returns `null`.

Which probably means that the element with `id` "tableForChange" does not exist on the page, at least when this javascript executes.

---

1. Is your javscript executing in the `<head>` tag before the body is built? If so move that code to execute `onload` instead.
2. You sure that element really exists? Perhaps there is a typo in your id somewhere.

Comment: The real question behind this is really: why is it null.